# Specify Maven repo per executor in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have read [online](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/01/painless-maven-builds-with-jenkins.html) that Jenkins releases since 1.448 let you specify a Maven repository per executor. But how does one exactly do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`http://your-jenkins-server/configure`**

[image]

A picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: Any idea if it can be specified only on certain slaves and not system-wide?

Comment: Not sure... But you could tie it to workspace, and have a job execute only on a specific node/slave, so that workspace will always be on that particular node

Comment: @Indrajeet: You can also do that on a job base!