# remote jenkins build vs local maven build

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for some clarity about Jenkins build and usage of local .m2 repository. When I build my maven project locally, using command

```
"mvn clean install -U"
```

maven locates a handful of jars in my local ~/.m2/repository. Jenkins I use, on the other hand, is running on a remote secure server that I access via browser. When Jenkins builds the same pom file that I build with the above command locally, it gets it from GitHub url that I specify in Jenkins configuration. Based on my observation, Jenkins only looks to download the jars from remote repositories stated in Jenkins settings.xml. It seems to me that Jenkins will never see or could use my local .m2 repository or any other local to my drive m2 folder. Is that true? Could someone with Jenkins knowledge please confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Jenkins will *not* be able to locate *your* local repository.
It will use its own local repository to download the dependencies to. (By default it is also `~/.m2/repository`.)

The local repository acts as a cache. [The documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) states:

> There are strictly only two types of repositories: local and remote. The local repository refers to a copy on your own installation that is a cache of the remote downloads, and also contains the temporary build artifacts that you have not yet released.

A further note: if you have multiple builds that access the same artifact in your local repository, this can cause problems. A good practice is to setup either "a private maven repository" per project or [per job or executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535232/specify-maven-repo-per-executor-in-jenkins).